# Thumbnail Grid with Expanding Preview not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've altered Codrops' [Thumbnail Grid with Expanding Preview](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/) so that the number of grid cells will change according to screen width by using basic css media queries.

You can see what I've done so far [here](http://www.oldo-nicho.com)

Everything appears fine at first but I've now found that when you click on the first cell that the expanded description box is underneath other cells and some of the subsequent cells are shifted around.

Also, if you refresh the page then you can change the width of the browser and the images will grow and shrink responsively. But after you click any of the images to reveal the description and then close the description then the clicked cell's height is fixed at that height and the page no longer behaves responsively with a different browser size.

Would anyone have any suggestions as to how I could go about fixing these problems?

Comment: It looks like a conflict with Bootstrap and being configured to adjust the sizing between mobile mode for different browser screen widths. I'm not too familair with Bootstrap, but if you can set up the Codrops elements of your site to isolate them from it.

Comment: Thanks @xzegga. I've tried removing all of the Codrops elements from any Bootstrap divs but it doesn't seem to help. However I have found that `grid.js` was setting the height of the elements in inline css when the preview blocks are expanded so that when the window size is changed it is fixed to that set height rather than expanding and contracting responsively. I added the following and it seems to have fixed that part of the problem:
`$(window).resize(function() {$('.grid-item').removeAttr('style');});`

Comment: Whoops, previous comment was intended to address @thril